# How to include an image in DataTable JQuery with MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I´d like to know, How can I include correctly an Image in a DataTable JQuery Plugin on my proyect MVC?

I´ve done de following but I get an alert error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyi5e.png)

This Is my code and the method within Controller that I use to get the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szibk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keu95.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you are showing data of row [1] that has a valid url.
The error refer to row 0 (see your image, it says error in row 0, col 4).
The url in record 0 has to be consistent.
here is the clause from datatable site:

- DataTables has requested data for a given row, of the {parameter}
  provided and there is no data there, or it is **null** or **undefined**
  (DataTables *doesn't know*, by default *how to display these parameters*
  see if your data does contain these values).

a possible solution is to set datatable option to show dedfult value for null:

```
    {
      "data": "UrlImagen", // can be null or undefined
      "defaultContent": "<i>No Image</i>"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I found the error and it was that the DataTables´ Configuration don´t accept arrow function to render a html tag, I had to put it rather  "data":"urlImagen", "render": function(data){  `<img src='/${data}'    `   }